# VHDL (Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Router.vhd(39) near text "port"; expecting "(", or "'", or ".")

Tags: syntax-error, vhdl

So basically I am doing the Mousetrap Latch controller on Altera and the syntax error keeps showing up (Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Router.vhd(39) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or ".").

```
    Library ieee; 
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
    use ieee.std_logic_arith.all; 
    use ieee.std_logic_signed.all; 

    entity Router is
    port(Ri, Ao, vld_i, rst: in std_logic; Data_i: in std_logic_vector(33 
    downto 0); Ro, Ai, vld_o: out std_logic; 
    Data_o: out std_logic_vector(33 downto 0));
    end entity Router;

    architecture behavioral of Router is
    signal reqI, ackO, VLDi: std_logic;
    signal reqO, VLDo: std_logic;
    signal Di, Do : std_logic_vector (33 downto 0);
    component latch1
    port(D, en: in std_logic; Q: out std_logic);
    end component;

    component latch_34
    port(D: in std_logic_vector(33 downto 0); en: in std_logic; Q: out 
    std_logic_vetor(33 downto 0));
    end component;
    begin

    process (rst)
    begin
    reqI<= Ri;
    ackO<= Ao;
    VLDi<=vld_i;
    Di<= Data_i;
    if (rst ='1') then
    reqI <= "0";
    ackO<='0';
    VLDi<='0';
    Di<= '0';
    Do<= '0';
    reqO<= '0';
    VLDo<= '0';
    else
    **u1: latch1 port map(reqI<=reqI, en<=reqO XNOR ackO, reqO<=reqO);**
    **u2: latch1 port map(VLDi, reqO XNOR ackO, VLDo);**
    **u3: latch_34 port map(Di, Not(reqO XNOR ackO) NAND VLDo, Do);**
    end if;
    end process;
    Ro<=reqO;
    Ai<=reqO;
    vld_o<= VLDo;
    Do<=Data_o;
    end behavioral;
```

Comment: A named association element is of the form *formal_port => actual_signal_or_expression*. Note you haven't specified whether this is -2008 or compliant with an earlier revision of the VHDL standard. Non globally static expressions (req0 XNOR ack0) are only supported in -2008 and not widely supported by synthesis tool vendors, (IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clauses, 6.5.7 Association lists).

Comment: You also can't instantiate a component (a concurrent statement) in a process (which may only contain sequential statements). You don't have conditional hardware. Components represent external blocks and are not called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [port map in structural VHDL code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164449/port-map-in-structural-vhdl-code)

Comment: For the OP's readers see [MOUSETRAP: High-Speed Transition-Signaling Asynchronous Pipelines](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.5283&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Montek Singh and Steven M. Nowick on CiteseerX.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment and thank you for the rest of the comments!

Comment: The second comment/duplicate post tells you why your code isn't valid syntax. Concurrent statements represent processes or blocks containing processes.  Sequential statements represent steps in an algorithm and describe behavior. Processes can't contain other processes, or processes and blocks (here instantiated latch1 and latch34). An elaborated design is comprised of block statements representing hierarchy and process statements communicating via signals. Move your component instantiations outside of the process and decide whether the latches work properly without a reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a "c" in std_logic_vector :

```
component latch_34
port(D: in std_logic_vector(33 downto 0); en: in std_logic; Q: out 
std_logic_vetor(33 downto 0));
end component;
```