# Error with VHDL port mapping an adder with unsigned variables

Tags: vhdl, vivado

So i made a 4 bit adder, and I wanted it port mapped to an ALU I am building, yet for some reason the port map is coming up as an error. I have tried everything, changing variable types, changing the logic, and even changing variable names, but nothing works. The error pops up when I try to use the port map (the lines where it says bit0, bit1...), and the error complains about the work 'port' and ';'.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
-- Define the input and output signals

ENTITY bit_FA IS
PORT (
    A, B : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
    CI : in std_logic;
    SUM : out unsigned(7 downto 0);
    CO : out std_logic);
END bit_FA;

-- Describe  the  full  adder 's behavior

ARCHITECTURE bit_FA1 OF bit_FA IS
signal tmp: unsigned(8 downto 0);
begin
    tmp <= A + B + ("0" & ci); --trick to promote ci to unsigned
    SUM <= tmp(7 downto 0);
    CO <= tmp(8);
END bit_FA1;

LIBRARY  IEEE;
USE  IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

-- Define  the  input  and  output  signals
ENTITY FinalLab IS
PORT (
    CLK : in BIT;
    code : in BIT_VECTOR;
    A: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    B : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    C, D : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    CO : out STD_LOGIC);
END FinalLab;

ARCHITECTURE behave_1 OF FinalLab IS

signal cin : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
component bit_FA is
port (
    a, b, c : in std_logic;
    sum, carry : out std_logic);
end component;

BEGIN
process(code)
begin
    if code = "000" then
        --error
        bit0 : bit_FA port map( A(0), B(0), '0', C(0), cin(0));
        bit1 : bit_FA port map ( A(1), B(1), carry(0), C(1), cin(1) );
        bit2 : bit_FA port map ( A(2), B(2), carry(1), C(2), cin(2) );
        bit3 : bit_FA port map ( A(3), B(3), carry(2), C(3), cin(3) );
        CO <= cin(3);
    elsif code = "001" then
        C(0) <= A(3);
        C(1) <= A(2);
        C(2) <= A(1);
        C(3) <= A(0);
    elsif code = "010" then
        --multiplication
        B <= std_logic_vector( unsigned(B) - 1 );
    elsif code = "011" then
        C <= std_logic_vector( unsigned(A) + 1 );
    elsif code = "100" then
        C(0) <= not(A(0) XOR B(0));
        C(1) <= not(A(1) XOR B(1));
        C(2) <= not(A(2) XOR B(2));
        C(3) <= not(A(3) XOR B(3));
    elsif code = "101" then
        C(0) <= not A(0);
        C(1) <= not A(1);
        C(2) <= not A(2);
        C(3) <= not A(3);
    elsif code = "110" then
        C(0) <= A(3);
        C(1) <= A(0);
        C(2) <= A(1);
        C(3) <= A(2);
    elsif code = "111" then
        C(0) <= A(1);
        C(1) <= A(2);
        C(2) <= A(3);
        C(3) <= A(0);
    end if;
end process;

END behave_1;
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate and entity inside a process. Entities must be instantiated outside a process. An entity is like a chip on a circuit board - it cannot be conditionally removed during runtime.

Comment: Component instantiations are concurrent statements. A process may only contain sequential statements. "=" with two different length expressions returns False and lack of else alternatives in if statements containing assignment can infer latches in synthesis when there are executions of the process that do not execute an explicit assignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [port map in structural VHDL code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164449/port-map-in-structural-vhdl-code)

Comment: yeah, I didn't realize that you couldn't instantiate within a process, which makes sense

Answer (score 1):

VHDL stands for VHSIC **Hardware** Description Language. As it is hardware, you cannot use if-statements and such to make components magically appear and disappear. All components need to be connected all the time.
What you *can* do is implement switched/multiplexers to select the output of components. However, you need intermediate signals.

I.e., the full adders need to be connected in the architecture scope and the output selected in the if statement

```
ARCHITECTURE behave_1 OF FinalLab IS
    signal FA_out : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    [...]
begin
    bit0 : bit_FA port map( A(0), B(0), '0', FA_out(0), cin(0));
    bit1 : bit_FA port map ( A(1), B(1), cin(0), FA_out(1), cin(1) );
    bit2 : bit_FA port map ( A(2), B(2), cin(1), FA_out(2), cin(2) );
    bit3 : bit_FA port map ( A(3), B(3), cin(2), FA_out(3), cin(3) );
    [...]
    if code = "000" then
        C <= FA_out;
        CO <= cin(3);
    [...]
```

Note: the `CLK` input port is there for a reason... use it.